# how to get startactivityforresult get result from 4th activity

Tags: android, startactivityforresult

I have `MainActivity` from that `startActivityForResult()` for 2nd `activtiy` but i want result from 4th `activity` what should i do for that?

> MainActivity
>
> FirstActivity
>
> secondActivity
>
> ThirdActivity
>
> FourActivity

from this i want result from 4th activity, but from secondactivity to fourth actity are dependent activities

**MainActivity.java**

```
public static String MY_RESULT=1000;

     intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstActivity.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,MY_RESULT);





 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_RESULT:
                    String info = data.getExtras().getString("KEY");


                    if(!info.equals("")) {
                        Log.i("TAAAG", info);

                    }

                    break;
}
}
}
```

**FirstActivity.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

**ThirdActivity.java**

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ThirdActivity.this, FourActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

**FourActivity.java**

```
  Intent intent = new Intent();


         intent.putExtra("KEY", "my data in string");

                        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);


      finish();
```

here in `MainActivity.java` Im not able to get any result.And I want result from `FourActivity.java`.Please help

Comment: But i want result from Fouractivity.java not from secondactivity.java

Comment: pass it in reverse , like from fourth to third , then to second.But if you finish Activities it is not possible, should use shared preference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way, you have to use `startActivityForResult()` for First to Third Activity and use `setResult()` in all to listen and pass back data.

Here's the sample code:

```
class FirstActivity extends Activity {

    public static int MY_RESULT = 1000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, MY_RESULT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == MY_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String dataStr = data.getStringExtra("KEY");
            Toast.makeText(this, dataStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}

class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, FirstActivity.MY_RESULT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == FirstActivity.MY_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            setResult(resultCode, data);
            finish();
        }
    }
}

class ThirdActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(ThirdActivity.this, FourthActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, FirstActivity.MY_RESULT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == FirstActivity.MY_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            setResult(resultCode, data);
            finish();
        }
    }
}

class FourthActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent data = new Intent();
        data.putExtra("KEY", "This is a test String");
        setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Other possible solutions include:

1. Defining your own `Singleton` which can hold data during App Session
2. Use `EventBus`
3. Use `SharedPreferences`
4. Use Local Database

Comment: Yes .Your code work for me with little modification in onActivityResult instead of resultCode == FirstActivity.MY_RESULT  change to resultCode==FirstActivity.MY_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK

Comment: I've added the change. This was just a sample how you can achieve it. Glad that it helped :)

Comment: @adnanyousafch gud effort.+1

Answer (score 0):

You can start each activity for result and pass your result like this:

```
FourthActivity -> ThirdActivity -> SecondActivity -> FirstActivity
```

In your Third, Second and First Activities use `onActivityResult` to get result from the previously closed `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

On fourth activity you set `RESULT_OK` in `setResult()` that is fine but in your `onActivityResult` just remove this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                String info = data.getExtras().getString("KEY");
                if(!info.equals("")) {
                    Log.i("TAAAG", info);

  }
}
```

Happy coding!!